# What happens when a shovel is deleted

Tags: rabbitmq

We have a queue which takes incoming data and pushes the data into another queue in another machine through a shovel.

For some reason, we found that the source queue had backed up with around 2M messages. We couldn't figure out the cause for that as it seemed that the destination queue and the consumer of that queue was working fine.

We also realized that the shovel was setup with the default pre-fetch count of 1000.

We are not able to modify the shovel to set a higher pre-fetch count, the only option is to delete the shovel and setup a new one with higher pre-fetch count.

What will happen if we delete the shovel ?
Will it delete the messages in the queues ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some information on the shovel you have setup?
Is the source exchange or queue? Same question for the destination?

Comment: So we have data coming into one queue attached to an exchange. The shovel is setup from that exchange to come to another Exchange and then to a queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment, if I understand correctly, you have:

```
RabbitMQ1 - exchange RMQ1EXCA -> queueA1

RabbitMQ2 - exchange RMQ2EXCB -> queueB1

A shovel has been configured, exchange [RMQ1EXCA] to exchange [RMQ2EXCB]
```

And you found out that the queueA1 is filled up with millions of message.

**If indeed this is an accurate depiction of your setup:**

- it's quite normal, as `queueA1` is not part of the shovel process
- if you check the queues bound to `RMQ1EXCA`, you should see one queue with a name starting with `amq.gen-......`
- deleting the shovel will not impact the `queueA1`, as it's not related to the process (but will delete the queue `amq.gen-......` that is)

If the description provided doesn't match your setup, please provide additional information to clarify your situation so that I can adapt my answer accordingly

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks